# How may I see the names of a separate Excel worksheet from within an active worksheet name-box?

Tags: excel-2010

I am using excel 2010

How may I see the names of a separate worksheet from within an active worksheet name-box please?

Regrads

Answer (score 0):

The Name box will only ever show names that you can use in the **current** sheet, i.e. workbook scoped and current sheet scoped names, not names scoped to other worksheets.

To see all names for a sheet, open the Name Manager, sort by Scope and scroll down to the worksheet name you are after.

Name Manager has a filter button to show workbook scoped versus worksheet scoped names, but you cannot filter on a specific worksheet.

Comment: I thought as much. Thanks

Comment: If that answers your question, please mark it as the answer. That's how you say "thank you" around here.